# Limiting results in query where MAX() still returns multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new here as I just jumped into the deep end (of the kiddie pool) learning SQL select queries. I have this SQL Developer made query:

```
select
    prod_prices.store_ID,
    prod_prices.prod_ID,
    prod_prices.supp_ID,
    MAX(prod_prices.promo_price) AS max_promo_price,
    prod_prices.sell_price,
    MAX(prod_prices.start_date) AS max_start_date
FROM
    prod_prices
WHERE
        prod_prices.store_ID = 3
    AND
        prod_prices.supp_ID = 1178
GROUP BY
    prod_prices.store_ID,
    prod_prices.prod_ID,
    prod_prices.supp_ID,
    prod_prices.sell_price
HAVING
    MAX(prod_prices.start_date) > '16.04.17'
AND
    MAX(prod_prices.start_date) < '17.05.17'
```

That returns:

```
"store_ID"  "prod_ID"   "supp_ID"   "MAX_promo_price"   "sell_price"    "start_date"
3       121752      1178        2           0,88        16.05.17
3       121752      1178        2           0,76        16.05.17
3       121754      1178        1           0,45        16.05.17
3       121756      1178        1           0,45        16.05.17
3       121758      1178        2           0,96        16.05.17
3       121758      1178        2           0,76        15.05.17
3       121760      1178        1           0,54        16.05.17
3       121762      1178        1           0,41        16.05.17
3       121764      1178        1           0,37        16.05.17
3       121766      1178        1           0,34        16.05.17
3       121773      1178        2           0,83        16.05.17
3       121773      1178        2           0,65        16.05.17
3       121777      1178        1           0,98        16.05.17
3       121779      1178        2           0,88        16.05.17
3       121779      1178        2           0,89        24.04.17
```

Since a product code can have more than one entry per latest start_date due to promo_price (1 = regular, 2 = sale price) and calucation reasons, I need to narrow that down so any unique prod_ID will only have a single entry (highest start_date, highest promo_price).
Unfortunately I don't know enough about queries to implement row_number() or partition by etc and I'd appreciate help a lot. If there are any good learning resources I'd appreacite them as well!

Comment: highest promo_price or highest sell_price? because highest promo_price is always 2 as per(1 = regular, 2 = sale price)?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I believe that your GROUP BY having the sell_price in it keeps group by from combining those into a single entry where all else is the same and the price varies.

I would remove the

```
GROUP BY sell_price
```

and modify

```
prod_prices.sell_price
```

to be

```
MAX(prod_prices.sell_price) AS max_sale_price,
```

this should get you each item listed with the max price of that item

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, didn't get a chance to access the db. The problem with using max_sale_price (or min, because the actual price in the store is going to be the lower, sale/promotional price) is it appears to be pulling the price from the entire table and not from the entries with the newest date entry.